# Does a blind character get a reflex save?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, saving-throw, conditions

A wizard cast a [Project Image](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/spells/projectImage.html) and switched to use its senses.
Meanwhile, somebody else cast a fireball on the body of the wizard.

I was wondering if the wizard could get a reflex saving throw, and if so, is it a full one ?

In RAW, Project Image just tells us the body is blinded and deafened.

> **Blinded** : The creature cannot see. It takes a –2 penalty to Armor Class, loses its Dexterity bonus to AC (if any), and takes a –4 penalty on most Strength- and Dexterity-based skill checks and on opposed Perception skill checks. All checks and activities that rely on vision (such as reading and Perception checks based on sight) automatically fail. All opponents are considered to have total concealment (50% miss chance) against the blinded character [..]<

There is nothing about saving throws in this, but it seems logical to me that being blind impair someone's ability to dodge something.

What do you think ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Yes, you are always allowed a save

Even an [unconcious character should be allowed a saving throw](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/69554/do-unconscious-characters-get-will-saves), regardless of their state. The fact that he is blind does not change how well he can protect his body against harm. Reflex saves are not only movement (dexterity), but also about luck (the dice roll) and training (the class bonus).

But since he does lose his dexterity to AC, a GM could rule that he also takes a penalty on his Reflex save, but that is a *house rule* and is up to the GM.

If the GM denies that character a Reflex save, then he will have some explaining to do when the rules say that a paralyzed (or unconcious) character are allowed to make Reflex checks with a -5 penalty but his character can't.

Answer (score 4):

Per RAW, I think you've answered your own question - there's nothing in there about a reduction to saving throw. You could interpret it as reacting to the heat of the incoming fireball, or snapping back to reality to partially shield yourself once the fireball hit, or something... get creative.

On the flip side, though, I would highlight this as a case where the rules, quite simply, can't encompass every scenario that will ever occur and thus can't be unconditionally applied forever and for always without amendment. I would agree with your closing assessment - it seems logical that this state of being would impair (if not completely negate) any reflexive reaction that could be taken. This would be a prime case for the GM to put on his referee hat and say "It doesn't matter what the rule book says. You can't see, you can't hear, you aren't moving... this fireball hits you, you don't get a reflex save."

Comment: On the other hand the GM may say "People throwing fireballs really don't need a buff vs anything because Wizards/Sorcerors are already overpowered as it is."

Answer (score 3):

By following the rules, being blind is not a problem to avoid a fireball. You quoted the full description of what being blind does and as you said there is nothing about saving throws.

You can try to handwave-explain that by saying you can actually know the fireball is coming, like maybe it does a big noise, makes air vibrates, etc.

However I completely agree this remains quite illogical and if the case was presenting in a game I run I would rule -4 to Reflex (as there is already a -4 to other dex stuff) but would still allow the save.