# Surviving Spiked Pit Traps

Tags: dnd-3.5e, damage, traps

**In terms of imagining the fiction in-game, how does a character survive being impaled by spikes in a spiked pit trap?**

***Spiked Pit Traps*** are a classic dungeon trap in fantasy.  Like most traps in D&D, they simply do a set amount of damage that can be survived.  It is assumed that if the character does survive the damage, they can simply climb back out (perhaps with the help of their allies and some rope) and continue on their way, making it a one-and-done kind of situation.

However, I find it difficult to imagine how someone would actually survive such an impaling regardless of damage rolls.  The realism and believably fails for me.  I see it as following a similar principle to **The Chunky Salsa Rule** - the character would be perforated so completely that there is no way to envision their survival.

In a spike trap with sufficiently dense amounts of spikes:

- The character could not avoid being pierced in every major body part, including through the head.  There'd be no way to "dodge" damage to certain body parts, as there's always more spikes.
- Even if the character survived the initial impaling, they would be unable to pull themselves off the spikes afterward due to gravity (unless they could magically fly straight up the way they fell).
- Even if the character someone dislodged themselves from the spikes, there would be no place to stand in order to prepare to get out of the pit, nor place for an ally to climb down to help them.

[image: Gonna die]

In real life, such a trap would almost certainly have a 100% fatality rate.  It is simply not possible to survive beyond some quantum-mechanical miracle.  Even then, actual miracles in D&D might still not save you - you couldn't plausibly be healed while you're still full of spikes.

**How do I deal with characters surviving such spike traps in terms of the narrative?**  How do I describe such an event in the story?  Is it even possible to make believable?  Should the Chunky Salsa Rule be applied such that such traps simply insta-kill instead?

Comment: I am genuinely interested in an answer, but I can offer that making a pit trap immediately lethal will result in your players roundly unionizing and striking. (Whether in the form of a walkout or by approaching the DM with blunted objects in hand depends entirely on the union.)

Comment: (I think bullet 3 may need revising. Presumably, the trap's *creator* didn't die in the trap. *Presumably.*)

Comment: On the one hand, this is a really interesting, good question, +1. But on the other, it seems very much like a *discussion prompt*, or a poll for ideas. I don’t think Stack Exchange is a good format for that discussion, as interesting as it is.

Comment: @HeyICanChan Trap creation, like other forms of construction, can use scaffolding or safety harnesses that would otherwise make it safer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a discussion prompt or poll for ideas, and cannot be authoritatively answered. It’s unclear how voting or accepting answers will work beyond simply being a popularity contest, and a discussion forum would be a far better place for that.

Comment: @KRyan I'd like to find a way to make this viable if possible.  This is a ***real problem*** insofar as I can't figure out how to describe such a situation when DMing.  It causes me a full-stop in my storytelling, which is bad.

Comment: @SouthpawHare Oh, I absolutely agree; I’d like to see it work too. But having users simply throw out ideas and see which ones get the most votes/your checkmark is not a good way for SE to function. And I just don’t see a good way to define how answers will be or should be judged. It kind of seems like “I’ll know it [an answer that works for me] when I see it.”

Comment: @KRyan I suppose my hope was that the answer wouldn't so opinion-based because, being so common of an issue, someone would just have a clear answer.  How do **other** people deal with this?  How do ***you*** do it?  Surely this has come up before.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68017/discussion-between-kryan-and-southpaw-hare).

Comment: @KRyan Unfortunately, chat does not work for me on the computer that I use during the day right now.

Comment: I, too, love the question, but I think it's indicative of a larger problem of survival generally. For example, [blind](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/95534/8610) and [sleeping](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/95588/8610) creatures get Reflex saving throws (in *Pathfinder* and *3.5e*), yet the game goes on. Lots of things that would (should? *do?*) instantaneously kill real-world folks don't kill fake-world folks so that it's a game of heroic adventure and exploration rather than *Corpse: The Role-playing Game.*

Comment: @HeyICanChan Keep in mind, I do not intend this as a "Why is it like this" kind of question.  It's more of a "What do I do when it happens?" question.  I'm not just pointing out how it's bizarre; I honestly want to know how to proceed.  Is the answer, "just crank up your suspension of disbelief, ignore it, and move on?"

Comment: I've closed this since I agree "how do I handle people surviving a thing that would rightfully kill them?" *is*, really, a discussion starter or a grounds for debate. People have all kinds of ways they think are the correct ways to handle stuff like this. Without scoping this down to, say, "what does the game say about this" or "how does the game text resolve/explain this", it's just opinion collection. (And I'm not sure there *is* a useful explanation in the game text -- its stance on HP has always been "you work it out".)

Comment: @doppelspooker "How do I deal with the mechanics saying that a character survives something fatal" seems like a reasonable soft question, along the lines of [How do I telegraph that an encounter that was too difficult before is now achievable?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/108560/how-do-i-telegraph-that-an-encounter-that-was-too-difficult-before-is-now-achiev). Many answers, but each can be self-contained.

Comment: @AceCalhoon Not a bad way of phrasing the question.  Would you like to be the one to ask it?

Comment: @SouthpawHare Nope. It's not my problem :) If you want to repurpose it for a new question and/or edit feel free... But it's Doppelspooker and the other open/close voters you need to appease.

Comment: @AceCalhoon That could be workable. I'm not sure at the moment how that will work out, but also not in a decent state of mind to judge. 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sub><sup>This is a bit of a tricky one, and one of the reasons why I (personally) dislike hit points. Regardless of my personal feelings, it's how things are. So how do people survive spiked pit traps?</sup></sub>

The real-world truth is that unless the character hits these spikes directly, at the perfect angle, they will bend some. As the character drops, they are initially impaled, but the moment (or "torque") they exert on the spikes cause the spikes to bend and to potentially break. A non-symmetric point on the spikes will also contribute to bending one way or another.

Additionally, any armor they are wearing (this is especially true of plate, chain, and shields) will deflect the spikes further, causing them to snap sooner.

So the character falls, the armor deflects most spikes, so the character gets a little impaled, but then the spikes break, preventing further damage.

Comment: Interesting!  I hadn't really considered the durability of the spikes.  I suppose as they deal damage to you, *you* also deal damage to *them,* making them less effective.

Comment: @SouthpawHare The unspoken problem here is that after the initial fall and break, you now have (very likely, anyways) new spikes. Either way, it's a point where the HP mechanics and the story don't really support each other.

Comment: That really bugs me, considering Spiked Pit Traps are a classic thing that appears *all the time.*

Comment: This answer also helps build verisimilitude— I tend to run mundane traps in my settings as being “old” and “used” unless being specifically subject to upkeep and maintenance by kobolds, or a diligent wizard, or something else actively repairing those traps. To that end, showing traps which have succeeded on an unfortunate party not only adds to the ambience of an old dungeon or jungle path, but also helps explain *why* a character might survive a deadly rock fall trap or pit trap: it’s already been used and so its efficacy has taken *at least* one significant reduction already.

Comment: @SouthpawHare You may want to consider alternative forms of health-tracking, such as this here: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/102000/combat-without-hp/102089#102089

Comment: @NFeutz ah! I never considered the "previously used" case!

Comment: @PipperChip — To be honest, I’d only used it as a cue to the players to be on their toes (“Where there’s one trap, there’s more!”); having a trap actively *break* was never something I’d considered. For the example of the case in question, the party might find a hundred year old spike pit trap - reduced to a mere “ten foot tall” - so that they know there might be *unsprung* traps further in.

Answer (score 2):

Hit points are an abstract way of telling you if your character is still able to act, it reflects your stamina, your ability to dodge attacks and what you might be searching for here is... the character's LUCK.

If a PC "fell" in a spiked pit, but wasn't reduced to 0 HP, it means he was able to grab a ledge and avoid falling for his death, but he might not get so lucky next time, hence his reduction to his Hit points.

But if he was reduced to 0 hitpoints, then he did fell on the spikes and I think it's reasonable to say that he was impalled to death.

Comment: Some systems are more or less abstract than others, though.  D&D 3rd edition especially seems pretty consistent with "HP damage means you literally got injured" (and likewise, healing means literally healing your wounds).

Comment: [Catching yourself when falling is a real thing in *3.5e*.](http://dndsrd.net/skillsAll.html#climb) A dude who did that wouldn't've been dealt damage. (However, narratively, the DM could describe the PC as having arrested his fall using a precarious, previously overlooked handhold *inside the pit* so that the PC only suffered minimal damage from those sharp sticks.)

Comment: @SouthpawHare Actually, that much is decidedly *untrue*. There are, in fact, options available in 3.5 that heal hp as a result of Extraordinary inspiration, and that’s just the most extreme example. Unfortunately, hp is an extremely broad, vague, and frankly *wonky* abstraction where you have to basically treat the loss of hp as... fluid. So you get situations where you narratively describe hp loss as getting lucky, but then describe hp healing as magic healing wounds. Just an unfortunate fact of the system.

Comment: That said, I feel like this explanation has a whole host of side-effects that cause problems for it. What if there is something you can only see from the bottom of the pit—does the person who fell in, and paid hp for the privilege of reaching the bottom, *not* get to see that thing because he actually grabbed the edge? @HeyICanChan’s suggestion is an improvement, avoiding some of those problems, but possibly not all. And this kind of back-and-forth is exactly the issue I had in mind when casting a close vote.

Comment: The way that taking damage is described vary from DM to DM. The golden rule of D&D is that the DM decides what happened, he sees a situation that isn't described in details in the book and adjudicates it. His question isn't about RAW, it's about how telling his players that their characters survived seemingly  impossible odds.
Questions here go beyond RAW and that doesn't mean they should be closed because of that.

Comment: @Manner At no point anywhere in my comments did I ever bring up RAW in any way. That is not my issue with the question. I’ll thank you to not put words in my mouth.