# Can a sleeping creature make a reflex save?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, saving-throw

What happens with the reflex save aspect of Burning Gaze if it is cast on a sleeping ogre with standard stats?

Assume the ogre failed the CON save. Since the ogre is sleeping, does the ogre get a full reflex save or is there some sort of penalty?

Comment: Technically different but same answer: http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/69554/do-unconscious-characters-get-will-saves

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### The ogre gets a save, but with a fairly large penalty.

The ogre is asleep? That means it's [unconscious](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/conditions/#TOC-Unconscious).

> **Unconscious**
> Unconscious creatures are knocked out and helpless. ...

[Helpless](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/conditions/#TOC-Helpless), eh?

> **Helpless**
> A helpless character is paralyzed, held, bound, sleeping, unconscious, or otherwise completely at an opponent’s mercy. A helpless target is treated as having a Dexterity of 0 (–5 modifier). ...

So the ogre gets to make a reflex save, but it *doesn't* get its normal dexterity bonus *and* it takes a -5 penalty.

<sub>Yes, I know nothing in the *rules* says that being asleep makes you unconscious, but we can assume that from knowledge of what the word "sleep" means. Also, the [designers said so](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2knrt?Sleep#5).</sub>